# How to trigger recompilation of a dependant project during a SBT build?

Tags: scala, sbt, code-generation

## Background

I have a complex code generation project called `migrationManager` with a recursive code generation strategy:

- `migration1` is used to generate `schema1`.
- `migration2` uses `schema1` to generate `schema2`.
- `migration3` uses `schema2` to generate `schema3`.
- etc.

In order to compile `migrationManager` and since the later migration files depend on files which are not generated yet, the files are brought in sequentially via `sbt` commands like such:

1. `sbt migrationManager/run update -c` This copies the next migration file into the `migrationManager` project.
2. `sbt migrationManager/run apply` and `sbt migrationManager/run codegen` produce the next code-generated schema.

When executing these manually via the terminal, and since we copy over the next migration file or generate the next schema, `sbt` detects the change in the source code and recompiles the project when the next run command is issued.

One way to automate this is with the watch version of the commands:

```
~sbt migrationManager/run update -c; migrationManager/run apply; migrationManager/run codegen
```

which detects source code changes and re-triggers these commands.

## Problem

My goal is to automate this within the build process, so I am writing a task which tries to loop through and run these commands.

The issue I'm running into is that when the next `sbt` run command is run, it does not detect the source code change and thus does not recompile before running the next command:

```scala
lazy val generateSchemas = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Generate database schema code based on migration files.")

// Migration manager receives the code changes from update command
lazy val migrationManager = project.settings(...)

lazy val app = project
  .dependsOn(migrationManager)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies,
    generateSchemas := {
      val cp = (Compile / dependencyClasspath).value
      val r = (migrationManager / Compile / runner).value
      val s = streams.value
      while (migrationsRemain > 0) {
        r.run("migrationManager.Application", cp.files, Seq("update", "-c"), s.log)

        // What can I do here to incrementally recompile migrationManager with the added source file?

        r.run("migrationManager.Application", cp.files, Seq("apply"), s.log)
        r.run("migrationManager.Application", cp.files, Seq("codegen"), s.log)
      }
      Seq(...)
    },
    Compile / sourceGenerators += generateSchemas.taskValue
  )
```

In the above example, the `apply` and `codegen` commands do not work properly because the copied migration file is not compiled into the project.

## Question

Is it possible to trigger a recompilation of the subproject `migrationManager` from within the `app` project's `generateSchemas` task I have defined above?

## Further Attempts

Looks like I can get hold of `migrationManager`'s compiler via:

```scala
val c = (migrationManager / Compile / compilers).value
```

within the task and from this value I can call compile like so:

```scala
c.scalac().compile(...)
```

which takes in a bunch of parameters:

```scala
compile(
  VirtualFile[] var1,
  VirtualFile[] var2,
  FileConverter var3,
  DependencyChanges var4,
  String[] var5,
  Output var6,
  AnalysisCallback var7,
  Reporter var8,
  Optional<CompileProgress> var9,
  Logger var10
): Unit;
```

but I'm not sure what to use as parameters (nor where I can see a trace of previous calls).

Is there a way to copy the values from the previous compilation of `migrationManager` so I can trigger it again from within my `app` project task?